# Error while automation an ssh command

Tags: python

I am trying to automate the below command for a list of gerrits and running into below error,can anyhelp to identify what the problem is and how to overcome it

COMMAND:-

```
ssh -p 29418 review-android.company.com gerrit query --format=JSON --current-patch-set --commit-message --files '530785'
```

CODE:-

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os

def main ():
    to = ''
    ssh_command = ["ssh", "-p", "29418", "review-android.quicinc.com", "gerrit",
                   "query", "--format=JSON", "--current-patch-set",
                   "--commit-message", "--files", ]

    with open('gerrit_output.txt', 'a') as fp:
        with open('caf_gerrits.txt','r') as f :
            for gerrit in f :
                gerrit = gerrit.strip()
                gerrit = gerrit.rstrip('\r\n')
                gerrit = str(gerrit)
                print "GERRIT"
                print gerrit
                print ssh_command
                result = subprocess.check_output(ssh_command + [gerrit, ])
                print result
                fp.write(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

ERROR:-

```
GERRIT
545804
['ssh', '-p', '29418', 'review-android.quicinc.com', 'gerrit', 'query', '--format=JSON', '--current-patch-set', '--commit-message', '--files']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 25, in <module>

  File "test.py", line 20, in main

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

Comment: FWIW, I can't reproduce your error with `gerrit = '545804'` which is what it looks like the value is in your post. (I get a `CalledProcessError` which isn't too surprising).

Comment: @mgilson - this is a different problem,,question was updated,its a repost  with updated code..

Comment: @mgilson - did you try putting the gerrits in a caf_links.txt file and it worked..

Comment: the file should have *nothing to do with it*.  If the exception is being raised in `subprocess`, then all that matters are the inputs to `subprocess`.  The loop over lines in the file just makes the question less clear.  See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) ...

Comment: Can you put in a `print all(isinstance(x, basestring) for x in ssh_command + [gerrit])` in there?  If that prints `False`, then that's your problem ...

Comment: @mgilson - it prints a True

Comment: Can you run other commands through subprocess?

Comment: @mgilson - can we try anything else other than subprocess..nothing seems to work with subproces checkoutput

Comment: You *can* use stuff in `os`:  `os.popen` or `os.system`, but really you should fix the problem rather than limping around with a busted install.  I'd suggest re-installing ...